# Stop ant script without failing build

Tags: ant, build, ant-contrib

In my ant script I want to exit (stop executing build) without failing when a condition is met. I have tried to use:

```
<if>
    <equals arg1="${variable1}" arg2="${variable2}" />
  <then>
    <fail status="0" message="No change, exit" />
  </then>
</if>
```

Ant script is stopped on condition but build is failed. I want to the build to be stopped but with no errors.  I'm using "Invoke Ant" step in Jenkins.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would a task called **`fail`** do anything other than fail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest to refactor your ant script by reconsidering your approach. If you approach your problem with "execution of a build when a certain condition is met" instead of "failing the build if another condition is met" it is easier to implement:

```
<!-- add on top of your build file -->
<if>
    <equals arg1="${variable1}" arg2="${variable2}" />
  <then>
    <property name="runBuild" value="true"/>
  </then>
  <else>
    <property name="runBuild" value="false"/>
  </else>
</if>


<!-- add to the target that shall be executed conditionally -->
<target name="myTarget" if="${runBuild}">
...

<!-- exit message as separate target -->
<target name="exitTarget" unless="${runBuild}">
  <echo message="No Change, exit" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 12):

Use builtin (since JDK 6) javascript engine,
no additional libraries (antcontrib .. etc.) needed !

***1. Java System.exit()***

```
<script language="javascript">
 self.log("Ending intentionally \n...\n..\n.");
 java.lang.System.exit(0);
</script>
```

you may get a BUILD FAILED when running in Eclipse :
BUILD FAILED
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException:
 Wrapped org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.AntSecurityException
=> then use Ant api instead

***2. Ant api***

```
<script language="javascript">
 self.log("Ending intentionally \n...\n..\n.");
 project.fireBuildFinished(null);
</script>
```

Output Eclipse, no BUILD SUCCESSFUL is printed :

```
   [script] Ending intentionally 
   [script] ...
   [script] ..
   [script] .
Total time: 410 milliseconds
```

Output Console, BUILD SUCCESSFUL is printed 2 times :

```
   [script] Ending intentionally
   [script] ...
   [script] ..
   [script] .

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Wrap in a macrodef for reuse, f.e. :

```
<macrodef name="stopbuild">
 <attribute name="condition"/>
 <attribute name="paramtype" default="math"/>
 <attribute name="param1"/>
 <attribute name="param2"/>
 <attribute name="when" default="true"/>
 <sequential>
 <script language="javascript">
 falsecondition = false;
 switch ("@{condition}")
 {
  case "lt" :
   b = "@{paramtype}" == "math" ? parseInt("@{param1}") &lt; parseInt("@{param2}") : "@{param1}" &lt; "@{param2}";
   break;
  case "gt" :
   b = "@{paramtype}" == "math" ? parseInt("@{param1}") &gt; parseInt("@{param2}") : "@{param1}" &gt; "@{param2}";
   break;
  case "eq" :
   b = "@{paramtype}" == "math" ? parseInt("@{param1}") == parseInt("@{param2}") : "@{param1}" == "@{param2}";
   break;
  default:
   self.log("Wrong condition : @{condition}, supported: lt, gt, eq");
   falsecondition = true;
 }
 if(!falsecondition &amp;&amp; b == java.lang.Boolean.valueOf("@{when}")) {
   self.log("Stopping Build because @{param1} @{condition} @{param2} is @{when} !!");
   java.lang.System.exit(0);
   // alternatively use
   //project.fireBuildFinished(null);
 }
 </script>
 </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Examples

```
 <!-- compare int, default paramtype=math and when=true -->
 <stopbuild param1="10" param2="11" condition="lt"/>
```

output :

```
[script] Stopping Build because 10 lt 11 is true !!
```

```
 <!-- compare strings, default when=true -->
 <stopbuild param1="abc" param2="abcd" paramtype="foo" condition="lt"/>
```

output :

```
[script] Stopping Build because abc lt abcd is true !!
```

Comment: IMO, it's an interesting solution but far more complicated than the accepted answer.

Comment: <script language="javascript">java.lang.System.exit(0);</script> ain't complicated, in fact it's the most simple.You don't need to put in a macrodef - that was just for demonstration. And after all it needs no external libs, simply using the builtin javascript engine.

Comment: There is a drawback to this approach that is higlighted. This is the 2nd approach is proposed. This one is quite heavy.

Comment: @Stephan "Far more complicated" is a big, big stretch my friend. There is absolutely nothing "heavy" about this, simple facts.

Answer (score 0):

Internally `<fail>` throws a `BuildException` to fail the build process, so, as long as you are using this task, you will get the ant build exit with errors.

Personally I don't know if there is any other task to "normally" exit the build, but writing one by yourself is not hard at all.

Writing a task which executes the following code should work...

```
public void execute() {
    // do something as you like
    System.exit(0);
}
```